# Making Parallax work on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, tablet, parallax

I've been looking and reading a lot about Parallax effect and I'm about to create my first Parallax site. One of my main concerns is about making it work on the iPad. I've read and seen enough to conclude that Parallax doesn't work as well on iPads.

Now, of all Parallax sites, I've found 2 that seem to work fine on iPads, but I still don't know what is it that they are doing differently for them to work, any ideas ?

Basically what I want to know is what are the differences between Parallax sites. I've seen some using the canvas tags, while other seem to be just adjusting top and left values, and others seem to be replacing images. Also, what's the best approach for an iPad friendly Parallax site.

The 2 sites I've found work fine on iPad are:

http://www.nike.com/jumpman23/aj2012/

https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My response is specifically for https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT

They are simulating scrolling depending on the type of input you are giving. You're not actually scrolling the page, and then animating the various properties. It's reading in the touch events, mouse wheel, or their custom baked scroll bar and seeing how much you are wanting to scroll. All of the content in the page is in a container. That way when you are doing a touch event, it's just reading how much you are moving on the page.

On top of that they are using an animation loop to make everything move. They are utilizing the window.requestAnimationFrame method in order to optimize the changes in their page so that it works smoothly on the iPad and in the browser. Here is a page with a description of it:

> http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
>   The browser can optimize concurrent animations together into a single
>   reflow and repaint cycle, leading to higher fidelity animation. For
>   example, JS-based animations synchronized with CSS transitions or SVG
>   SMIL. Plus, if you're running the animation loop in a tab that's not
>   visible, the browser won't keep it running, which means less CPU, GPU,
>   and memory usage, leading to much longer battery life.

On top of that they have built a custom keyframe object that will decide on how everything is animated on the page. I'm drooling over this set up. Too bad it's not an open framework. You can set where the effect starts, where it ends, the easing, etc. just in the keyframe object, and their framework will handle all of the rest through the animation loop.

```
{
    selector: '#outro2 > .content2',
    startAt: outroStart+500,
    endAt: outroStart+1000,
    onEndAnimate:function( anim ) {},
    keyframes: [
        { 
            position: 0,
            properties: {
                "margin-top": 650
            }

        },
        {
            position: 1,
            ease: TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.EaseOut,
            properties: {
                "margin-top": 650
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

In summary, I believe the combination of custom implemented scrolling, and a custom animation loop using the requestAnimationFrame method get beyond the parallax limitation normally associated with iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I've had a look at the code, and I found this:

```
  // touch
  function touchStartHandler(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    touchStart.x = e.touches[0].pageX;

    // Store the position of finger on swipe begin:
    touchStart.y = e.touches[0].pageY;

    // Store scroll val on swipe begin:
    scrollStart = scrollTop;
  };

  function touchEndHandler(e) {

  }

  function touchMoveHandler(e) {

    /*if (settings.freezeTouchScroll == true) {
      $('#status2').html('freezin');
      return false;
    };
    $('#status2').html('moovin');
    */

    e.preventDefault();
    offset = {};
    offset.x = touchStart.x - e.touches[0].pageX;

    // Get distance finger has moved since swipe begin:
    offset.y = touchStart.y - e.touches[0].pageY; 

    // Add finger move dist to original scroll value
    scrollTop = Math.max(0, scrollStart + offset.y);
    checkScrollExtents();
  }
```

I haven't tried that code my self, but I believe that's what you need.
I'll give it a try and let you know if that's all you need.